# How to configure DBeaver for Ubuntu, PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, dbeaver

I'm new to DB viewers and DBeaver.
I installed DBeaver on Ubuntu 16.04 to view the DB tables of my project, chose 'PostgreSQL', entered username and password, clicked 'test connection' and got an error: 
`Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`
How do I configure it to access my project tables?

UPD
I installed DBeaver under vagrant virtual machine, and managed to connect, but don't see any tables and my project. Why?

Comment: Do you have Postgres installed and running on your machine?

Comment: 'which psql' in the console returns '/usr/bin/psql', so I guess it means yes (under vagrant virtual machine).

Answer (score 0):

If you use "localhost" as the host, your project and DBeaver need to be on the same machine (virtual or physical). Otherwise, in DBeaver, you need to enter the IP address of the machine on which Postgres is installed and running.

Additionally, make sure you select "Show non-default databases" in your connection settings to see all databases on the server you connect to. To switch to a non-default database, right click it and select "Set active."